# Add values if available with maybe() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently use the following maybe() function in my code to add data if available. I wonder if there is a better way to write that. It seems a bit long, or is that the best way to write it?

```
<Formik
  initialValues={{
    firstName: user.firstName,
    lastName: user.lastName,
    timezone: user.timezone,
    email: user.email,
    headline: maybe(() => user.headline, "") || "",
    profilePicture: maybe(() => user.profilePicture, "") || "",
  }}
>
  [...]
</Formik>;
```

utils.js

```
export function maybe(exp, d) {
    try {
      const result = exp();
      return result === undefined ? d : result;
    } catch {
      return d;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you just mean `user.headline || ''` ? If `user.headline` is null or undefined, it will fall back on the default value of `''`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, `user.header || ""` is ok, but I would recommend using [optional chaining `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) in case the object is undefined

```js
const user = {
    header: 'hello world'
}

console.log( undefined?.header || "default" ); // default

console.log( user?.header || "default" ); // hello world

console.log( user?.doesNotExist || "default" ); // default

console.log( undefined.header || "default" ); // error
```